# Como tratar vários forms em uma mesma pagina.aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho uma pagina.aspx que tenho vários forms. Um dos forms coloquei **runat="server"** e está do tipo **Textbox**, consegui pegar os dados do form e inserir no banco. Porém queria fazer o mesmo com os outros forms, mas não sei como fazer isso. Pois, não é possível ter mais de um **form server="runat"** na mesma página.

Como faço pra receber os dados dos outros forms na minha class?

Segue os códigos dos meus form's:

```
<!-- Modal Veículos -->
    <div id="myModal_Veiculos" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <form id="Cad_Veiculos">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3>Cadasto de Clientes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Placa </label><input type="text" id="placa" name="placa" />
                <label>Quilometragem </label><input type="text" id="quilometragem" name="quilometragem" />
                <label>Cor </label><input type="text" name="cor" id="cor" />
                <label>Tipo </label><input type="text" name="tipo" id="tipo" />
                <label>Ano </label><input type="text" name="ano" id="ano" />
                <label>Chassi </label><input type="text" name="chassi" id="chassi" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Fechar</button>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary"onclick="button1_cad_cliente">Salvar</Button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    <!-- Modal Clientes -->
    <div id="myModal_Clientes" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
        <form id="clientes" runat="server">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3>Cadasto de Clientes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Nome </label><asp:TextBox id="nome_clientes" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <label>CPF </label><asp:TextBox id="cpf_clientes" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <label>RG </label><asp:TextBox id="rg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <label>Endereço </label><asp:TextBox id="endereco" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <label>Telefone </label><asp:TextBox id="telefone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <label>E-mail </label><asp:TextBox id="email_clientes" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Fechar</button>
            <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" Text="Salvar" runat="server" onclick="button1_cad_cliente"></asp:Button>
        </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Amigo, sua pergunta contém erros de digitação é **runat="server"**, e depois como que um form vai ser do tipo TextBox? A menos que seja UM campo do <form>... Enfim verifica ae...

Comment: Mas o Texbox, se vc observar bem, está envolvido por um form.

Comment: Sim, isso é visto, é que tu tinha dito da forma incorreta!

Comment: O link que você mandou é parecido com minha dúvida. Mas não foi suficiente para tirar minha dúvida. Mas valeu.

Comment: Dá uma olhada novamente... fiz um update.!

Answer (score 1):

Cara, dá uma olhada no meu comentário também, mas para responder sua pergunta é simples!

Dá uma olhada nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544454/can-we-use-multiple-forms-in-a-web-page), que irá te sanar suas dúvidas!

Valeuu! :D

**UPDATE 01**

Você deve setar uma action e um method no form que não tem runat="server", porque o asp net não permite dois forms com runat="server", operando na mesma página.

Sugiro que analise sua estrutura e crie um WebUserControl, ou mova um destes formulários para uma outra página aspx. E não não é possível recuperar nessa mesma página os valores desses dois forms! :D

Entendeu?!

Comment: Entendi sim. Vou tentar e em breve entro em contato contigo.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo, de como recuperar páginas asp.net pra minha página principal? Tenho essa dúdivas, porque sou novato com C# webforms.